# Issue with replacing Json variable with shell script value using curl

Tags: bash-scripting, curl, json

```
#!/bin/bash
#CONFIG_FILE_PATH is the path of the json file as argument while running the script
CONFIG_FILE_PATH=$1
CUST_NAME=$2
curl -X POST -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data-binary @$CONFIG_FILE_PATH "http://localhost:8080/service"
```

Below is the json where i am trying to substitute ${CUST_NAME} with shell script variable CUST_NAME. 
    But not working. Can someone help on this?

```
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "query": "select * from customer where account_name like '${CUST_NAME}'"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you use `CONFIG_FILE_PATH` in you `curl` line, it will not be read and parsed by the shell, so no variable substitution takes place. There are many ways around this, but I prefere to do my own replacement via `sed`:

JSON template:

```
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "query": "select * from customer where account_name like '##CUST_NAME##'"
        }
    ]
}
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#CONFIG_FILE_PATH is the path of the json file as argument while running the script
CONFIG_FILE_PATH=$1
CONFIG_FILE=$(cat "$CONFIG_FILE_PATH" | sed "s/##CUST_NAME##/$2/g")
curl -X POST -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data-binary "$CONFIG_FILE" "http://localhost:8080/service"
```